# Execute server side code after client side confirmation only

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to display a client side confirmation after calculating a complex formula server side. Something like

```
//Server side
        On ButtonClick(){
            FetchRate(field1,field2,.... fieldn);
            // Show Client side confirmation
            // Execute server side code if confirmed client side 
    }
```

What I have done is created a client side function but my server side code always executes on postback no matter what I select client side

```
// Server side    
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ConfirmAction('"+ myRate +"');", true);
//Client side
    function ConfirmAction(myRate) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure?. Rate is exceeding '+ myRate +', proceed ?')) {
                document.getElementById('hfSaveUpdate').value = 1;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Ajax Model Popup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) & handle its ok & cancel button.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModelPopupID" runat="server"  
    TargetControlID="LinkButton1"  
    PopupControlID="Panel1"  
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"   
    DropShadow="true"   
    OkControlID="OkButton"   
    OnOkScript="onOk()"  
    CancelControlID="CancelButton"   
    PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel3" />
```

Launching a Modal Popup Window from Server Code:

Server Side Code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "launchModal();", true);
```

Client-Side Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var launch = false;
 function launchModal() 
 {
 launch = true;
 }
function pageLoad() 
 {
 if (launch) 
 {
 $find("ModelPopupID").show();
 }
 }
</script>
```

On ok click of the model popup, execute you server-side after conformation code.
On cancel button click, just hide the model popup window.

For more details, check this:

[ModalPopup Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/modalpopup/launching-a-modal-popup-window-from-server-code-cs)

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a client-side action in between server-side code.

Your code prepares the client-side confirm, but doesn't send it to the browser until the response is completed. The server then immediately continues to process your data. When it is done, the response is sent to the browser and the user sees the confirmation dialog. Too late: the data has already been processed. And the result of the dialog never gets sent to the server.

You will need to split the process into two: first get confirmation about that rate (maybe using ajax) and then submit the form to be processed/stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `onclientclick attribute` on your button

Link  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.80).aspx